# How can I productively widen the 'Name' column, for all folders?

Tags: windows

Please see the GIF beneath. 
Widening this column for the 'Pierre Boulez - The Complete Works' folder manually, didn't widen the subfolders automatically. The 12 subfolders' 'Name' columns are too narrow, and fails to exhibit the whole name, but it's too unproductive to widen the 12 subfolders separately. How can I widen them simultaneously?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may apply a specific folder view to all folders with the same folder template.

The template can be seen by right-click of the folder and choosing *Properties*,
under the *Customize* title:

[image]

You can choose between having General Items, Documents, Pictures, Music, or Video as the default folder template for the folder.

After setting the folder's type, enter the folder and set the width of the columns
as desired.

Then go to the ribbon *View > Options > Change folder and search options*, *View* tab,
and click the button *Apply to folders*:

[image]

Note that the folder view of Computer, Favorites, and Library folders cannot
be applied in this way, and the above button will be grayed out for these folders.

---

Another method to swiftly adjust the sizes of all columns to show all data,
is to click in the *View* ribbon pane the button *Size all columns to fit*,
or alternatively type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad+</kbd>.

This will immediately resize all columns to the exact size of their contained
data.

For more details, see the article
[How to Size Width of All Columns to Fit for Folder in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/35200-size-all-columns-fit-folder-windows-10-a.html),
which even contains a method for setting the width of selected columns
in pixels.